# All built-in javascript Objects

Tags: javascript

I need to get list of all javascript objects. In other words i need all NameOfXObject, for which such x exists, that:

```
x+""
will return "[object NameOfXObject]"
```

for example:

```
document+""         --> "[object HTMLDocument]"
window+""           --> "[object Window]"
locationStorage+""  --> "[object Storage]"
```

To sumarize:
I need list containing: "HTMLDocument", "Window", "Storage"...

I've tried

```
Object.keys(window)
```

But it not returns all objects

Thanks in advance, sorry for my english

Comment: `Object.keys()` gets you the keys. Loop over the keys and get each value: `window[key]`.

Comment: There's not really a complete repository of all object types. For example, you can only get an instance of [`ImageData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ImageData) by creating a canvas element and calling [`getImageData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/getImageData) or [`createImageData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/createImageData).

Comment: `Object.keys` will only return non-inherited values. Window is an object that can have inherited (prototypical) values. You'll need to loop through the object using something like `for(i in window)` in order to get all of the keys. Also not all objects are children of the `window` object.

Comment: @MikeC Have you tried? I can get an instance in Chrome by calling `new ImageData(true, true)`.

Comment: @JonathanGray Okay, fair point. I should have tested it first. The point is, as you said, not all objects are children of the `window` object so there's not some central place you can go to get all of the types.

Comment: So, i've tried @Blender proposition, i have following objects: Window
History
BarProp
Navigator
External
OfflineResourceList
Screen
Performance
CacheStorage
Console
Crypto
IDBFactory
Storage
HTMLDocument
InstallTriggerImpl

Comment: But there isnt for example Math object, which also works fine with Math+"", so I assume that window[Object.keys(window)] will not return all objects, any other suggestions how to archieve that?

Comment: Instead of `+""` you could use `.toString()`... However I think you're out of luck as there is no universal way of obtaining constructors in JavaScript unless you already have instances of the objects that you want constructors for.

Comment: To be honest I am searching for specific one, only thing i know is that it is 24 letters long ;/

Answer (score 0):

You need to traverse the prototype chain of `window` with [Object.getOwnPropertyNames](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames) to get all the properties attached to it.

```
var target = window,
    result = [];

do {
    result = result.concat(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(target));
} while(target = Object.getPrototypeOf(target))

result = result
    //Filter out properties such as "onclick" which are null by default
    .filter(function(r){ return window[r] != null; }) 
    //Optional: filter out those whose type is not "object"
    .filter(function(r){ return typeof window[r] === 'object'; });
```

---

For me (Chrome v50 in this very page) filtering the results to only include property names whose length is 24 returned

```
["SpeechSynthesisUtterance", "PresentationAvailability", "BeforeInstallPromptEvent", "CanvasRenderingContext2D", "SVGRadialGradientElement", "SVGLinearGradientElement", "SVGFEGaussianBlurElement", "SVGFEDistantLightElement", "SVGAnimatedTransformList"]
```

but all of those are functions instead of objects and thus for those `x+''` will give something more like `"function SpeechSynthesisUtterance() { [native code] }"` so I'm not sure if it contains what you were trying to find.

---

To get a list containing the string representations like `['[object Math]', ...]`, add

```
    //Get the string representation of the global object
    .map(function(r){ return window[r] + ''; });
```

For me, one of those had the length of 24: `'[object SpeechSynthesis]'`

Comment: A tip for overcoming the string output anomaly... Every constructor should have a `.name` value. ;)

Comment: Sure, I just don't know how strict requirement the `x+""
will return "[object NameOfXObject]"` thing is for OP.